# Find probability of $ |X-Y|≥1/2 $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I can't seem to find the answer. The complete problem statement is.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and both uniformly distributed in the interval from 0 to 1,
find $P( |X-Y|\geq 1/2 ).$

Comment: Hint: Consider the $[0,1]^2$ and what is the area of the region (x,y) such that $|x-y|\ge \dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: Try sketching in the $x,y$ plane, the set of values satisfying $|x-y|\ge 1/2$.

Comment: **Suggestion:** Draw a picture, highlighting the portion  $\{(x,y): |x-y|\ge 1/2\}$ of the unit square corresponding to the random variable inequality.

Comment: PDF of $X-Y$ is a convolution between the PDF of $X$ and $-Y$. Thus it is an isosceles triangle with base $[-1,1]$. Easy to see that the answer is $0.25$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $|x-y|\geq \frac{1}{2}$ is given by $x-y\geq\frac{1}{2}$ or $x-y\leq -\frac{1}{2}$, which we can write as $y\geq x+\frac{1}{2}$ or $y \geq x-\frac{1}{2}$. Then together with the constraints $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$, we want to find the area bounded by the regions $0\leq x\leq 1$, $0\leq y\leq 1$, $y\geq x+\frac{1}{2}$ and $y \geq x-\frac{1}{2}$. This gives an answer of $\frac{1}{4}$ ([here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hrjypyiqnx) for the graph).